# The pregnancy tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed

When posting my question about [Postpartum haemorrhages due to partial placenta detachment or tear](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/17620/postpartum-haemorrhages-due-to-partial-placenta-detachment-or-tear) it seemed that I couldn't create a [obstetrics](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obstetrics) tag however, I later found that the tag was already created, but switches to [pregnancy](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pregnancy) as obstetrics is set as a [synonym of pregnancy](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/tags/pregnancy/synonyms).

Should this not be the other way round if we are going to trim the number of tags used?  Pregnancy, childbirth, and the postpartum period are all parts of the obstetrics umberella term used in medical science, all of which could have been used for my question.

Comment: Good point. Done.